# Logarithms in calc ulat or vs those in book

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, discrete-logarithms

When I look for log base 10 of 0.496 in log books(Clark's table) it is somewhat bar1. 655 with some point .But using a calculator I am getting -0.345. so why is it different.

Comment: What does "bar1.655" mean?

Comment: Note that $.655+.345=1$ ... How should the numbers in the table be interpreted ?

Comment: Please write more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bar 1.655$ means $-1+0.655=-0.345$. In old days when we can only find logarithms using tables, it was common to use this notation. We find $\log 4.96$ from table, obtaining the value $0.655$. $\log 0.496=\log 4.96-1=\bar 1.655$.

Comment: Thank you fellow math exchanger